# Return string without vowels in python

Tags: python, string, list

I want to take a string and print it back without the vowels for Ex: for `'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'`, I want to get `'th qck brwn fx jmps vr th lzy dg'`.

I have tried using list comprehension, but I am only able to split the sentence into a list of words, I can't further split the words into individual letters in order to remove the vowels. Here's what I've tried:

```
a = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
b = a.split()
c = b.split()
d = [x for x in c if (x!="a" or x!="e" or x!= "e" or x!="i" or x!="u")]
e = ' '.join(d)
f = ' '.join(f)
print(f)
```

Comment: `result = "".join(i for i in a if i not in "aeiou")` ?

Answer (score 1):

You won't need to split the original string, since looping through a string in Python iterates through the characters of the string.

Using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), you just check if the current character `char` is a vowel and exclude it in such a case.

Then, at the end, you can join up the string again.

```
a = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
s = [char for char in a if char not in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')]
print(''.join(s))
# th qck brwn fx jmps vr th lzy dg
```

If your sentence may contain uppercase vowels, and wish to filter those out as well, you can do so using [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20lower#str.lower):

```
s = [char for char in a if char.lower() not in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')]
```

Comment: you might want to change the code to check for capital vowels instead of just making the string lowercase as he asked to return without vowels not make it smaller

Comment: @mtvare what do you mean? both versions above *remove* the vowels - the use of `.lower()` is for the purposes of comparison only

Comment: oops i didn't see that you just used for comparison, i had thought you changed them

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [costaparas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65662859/12373956) or also use regexes to remove vowels

```py
import re
se = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
se = re.sub(r"[aeiouAEIOU]", '', se)
```

`re.sub` replaces all occurence of the regex with second string

Comment: on inspection, this appears to be ~2x as fast as a list comprehension such as `result = "".join(i for i in a if i not in ("a","e", "i", "o", "u"))`

Comment: @anon01 *twice* as fast sounds surprising. What length strings are involved in that analysis, vowel/non-vowel ratio?

Comment: feel free to try on your machine, e.g. : `se = a*100000`, `%timeit re.sub(r"[aeiouAEIOU]", '', se)`, `%timeit "".join(i for i in a if i not in ("a","e", "i", "o", "u"))`

Answer (score 0):

Please do this you will get your answer:-

````
    vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')  
    for x in string.lower(): 
        if x in vowels: 
            string = string.replace(x, "") 
              
    # Print string without vowels 
    print(string) 
  
your_string = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
vowel_remove(your_string) ```

I tried and get a result which you can see in given image:-

`developer@developer-x550la:~/MY_PROJECT/Extract-Table-Pdf/extractPdf$ python3 stak.py
 
th qck brwn fx jmps vr th lzy dg
`
````

Answer (score 0):

Simple one-liner with `filter`:

```
>>> s = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
>>> ''.join(filter(lambda x: x not in 'AEIOUaeiou', s))
'th qck brwn fx jmps vr th lzy dg'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']

se = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'

for vowel in vowels:
    se = se.replace(vowel,'')
```

With the `replace()` method

Comment: The second version 1) will fail because strings aren't mutable (raises an error) and 2) it's not a good idea to modify iterables in place.  You will run into an index error sooner or later